# How do I implement a filter on a data returned from the store in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, filter

I have a .js file with the following:

```
Vue.mixin({    
data() {    
    return {    
        searchFilterSetupBase: {    
            BasisMasterIdEx: {    
                Title: this._rsc('Basis', 'Basis'),    
                Component: 'CheckboxListSelect',    
                SingleSelect: true,    
                Source: this.$store.state.storage.lists.BasisMasters//,    
            }    
        }    
    }    
},
```

This works returning the data from the store.
However, I want to filter this data but can't get it to work.
I have tried replacing Source: this.$store.getters.getBasisMasterById() and using a getter as below:

```
getters: {    
    getBasisMasterById: state => {    
        if (this.$store.state.storage.lists.BasisMasters) {    
            return this.$store.state.storage.lists.BasisMasters.filter((basisMaster) => {    
                return basisMaster.t === ('STAT')    
            })        
        }    
    }    
},
```

I tried to do something like https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access
but just dont know how to implement it. Please help

Editing my post.
I tried the following with getters:

```
Source: this.$store.getters['movies']



getters: {      
    movies: state => this.$store.state.storage.lists.BasisMasters      
},  

computed: {      
    movies() {      
        alert('aaaa');      
        return state.getters['movies']      
    },
```

Comment: In your first code example you're not using a getter by directly accessing the state.
If you implement a getter you have to use that getter and not access the state directly. Not sure if you did that, you're not making that clear from your question.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. In my first code, (when I get all the data) I do not implement a getter but I access the state directly.

Comment: Yeah but have you tried using the getter? The getter doesn't trigger automatically just because you accessed the property :)
In general Vuex recommends using getters/actions instead of checking/mutating the state directly by the way. It's not mandatory of course.

Comment: Hi, I edited my original post. As you suggested above, I tried out different combinations but I just can't get the store to working via the getter.